# Add instance methods to User object that uses related models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using a custom user model, similar to the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) and I want to attach some instance methods to this user model.

Lets say I have some other models also, such as Items, Polls, ForumPost, BuySell, UpDownVote etc, which all has a foreign key to the user model.

What I want to achieve then, are some custom methods that I can call on an user object, for example, on a summary page. Things like:

```
user.total_items()     - Counts the total items a user has
user.last_forum_post() - Last post the user has made
user.updown_vote_sum() - The sum of all Up and Down votes the user has retrieved
```

How do I achieve this? And how do I achieve it the best way?

I guess I could just add a lot of methods to my custom User model, that then does something like **Items.objects.filter(user=self).count()**. But, would that be the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [backward relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).  For example:

```
def total_items(self):
    self.item_set.all().count()
```

If you want to write the logic in the `Items` model instead of `User` then you have to import this model inside the `User`'s method:

```
def total_items(self):
    from items.models import Items
    return Items.objects.count_for_user(self)
```

The `Items` model/manager will be something like this:

```
class ItemsManager(models.Manager):

    def count_for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user).count()

class Items(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = ItemsManager()
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks better than my initial thought! But, is there some way I can write the logic in the "correct" models, and like, "import" them on my user model? If possible, I want things to be a little more loosely coupled.

Comment: See the updated answer.  But I think my first option is better.

Comment: Yeah, I agree on the first answer looking better. I think I'll go with that one for now. I'll let the question be open a while longer before accepting though, if someone else has some other answer to it.